# Parse Server Upgrade to v4.2: Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I have recently upgraded parse-server to v4.2. I have also updated Mongo to v4.2 (It's a Replica Set configuration). Now when parse-server is raised, the following error appears "Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses: Tried to ensure field uniqueness for a class that already has duplicates."

The detailed error is this:

```
{
"message": "Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses: Tried to ensure field uniqueness for a class that already has duplicates.",
"code": 137,
"level": "warn",
"stack": "Error: Tried to ensure field uniqueness for a class that already has duplicates.\n    at _adaptiveCollection.then.catch.error (/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoStorageAdapter.js:569:15)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)"
```

The error is caused by the `_User` class that has the username and email fields with the same data.
Any ideas on how to fix the problem or make the parse-server not do this check.

Comment: Edit or delete offending documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that a unique index could not be created on the `email` field.

The unique index ensures that in the `email` field a value can only occur once, in other words, that it occurs uniquely. MongoDB cannot create such an index if there are already duplicate values in the `email` field that would violate the rule of uniqueness, in other words, an identical email address already appears multiple times in the collection.

Keep in mind that Parse Server 4.0 [introduced](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#40) a case-insensitive index for the the field `email` and `username`. If you already have a user with email `email@example.com` and another one with `EMAIL@example.com`, the index creation will also fail.

The solution is to remove the duplicate email entries and restart Parse Server, so that index creation will be attempted again.